# how to use sql query in sql query

Tags: php, sql

I have two tables:

1. table category(cat_id,category)
2. table category_details(cat_id,id,...)

I have sql code like bellow:

```
$sql=mysql_query("select * from category");
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$id_count=$rows['cat_id'];      

$sql1=mysql_query("select * from category_details where cat_id='$id_count'");
$count=mysql_num_rows($sql1);

}
```

Can I use like this?

Comment: What are you doing with this?

Comment: "Can I use like this"... Yes

Comment: How? Can you show me please?

Comment: I want to create a category of products and each category have many products in it. So I just want to select all category to show on website and count the products of each category, for example(Hotels(20),Guesthouse(15)) just like that.

Answer (score 3):

Use `JOIN`.

**Example**

```
SELECT * FROM category LEFT JOIN 
   category_details ON category_details.cat_id = category.cat_id;
```

above query will return all the `category` and associated `category detail`.

**OP Comment Response**

```
SELECT    c.name,
          IFNULL(sub_c.total, 0) num
FROM      category c
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT   COUNT(*) total, cat_id
            FROM     category_details
            GROUP BY cat_id
          ) sub_c ON (sub_c.cat_id = c.cat_id);
```

**Complete Code**

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT    c.name,
                IFNULL(sub_c.total, 0) num
            FROM      products_category c
                LEFT JOIN ( SELECT   COUNT(*) total, cat_id
                    FROM     product
                    GROUP BY cat_id
                ) sub_c ON (sub_c.cat_id = c.id)";

    $result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());

    echo "<table><tr><td>NameCount</td></tr>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row['name']."(".$row['num'].")"."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

**MySQL Table**

**ProductCategory Table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products_category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `products_category`
--

INSERT INTO `products_category` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Erasmus'),
(2, 'Preston'),
(3, 'Ulric'),
(4, 'Gray'),
(5, 'Joseph'),
(6, 'Merrill'),
(7, 'Alan'),
(8, 'Jeremy'),
(9, 'Solomon'),
(10, 'Andrew'),
(11, 'Galvin'),
(12, 'Craig'),
(13, 'Cameron'),
(14, 'Omar'),
(15, 'Addison');
```

**Product Table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `product`
--

INSERT INTO `product` (`id`, `name`, `cat_id`) VALUES
(1, 'Wesley', 1),
(2, 'Graiden', 2),
(3, 'Cruz', 5),
(4, 'Hayden', 5),
(5, 'Kennedy', 6),
(6, 'Uriah', 8),
(7, 'Alan', 8),
(8, 'Cade', 1),
(9, 'Ryan', 5),
(10, 'Brody', 7);
```

**Above will output**

```
Erasmus(2)
Preston(1)
Ulric(0)
Gray(0)
Joseph(3)
Merrill(1)
Alan(1)
Jeremy(2)
Solomon(0)
Andrew(0)
Galvin(0)
Craig(0)
Cameron(0)
Omar(0)
Addison(0)
```

Comment: I want to show like this: for example i have 2 records of table category Hotel,Guesthouse and then in each record have many records and i want to select all category records and count how many sub record in each look like this (Hotel(15), Guesthouse(9))

Comment: @user1116954 so you can use subquery and add count into it

Comment: it still not working for me. Ok can you show me the sample code. I have table products_category and table products, in each products_category have many products in it. I just want to show it like this e.g: book(30),pen(15), it mean in book category have products 30 and pen category have products 15 in it.

Comment: @Bee okay give me few minute i setup in my local

Comment: Thank you so much. That what i want. I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to use `COUNT` with `GROUP BY`:

```
select c.cat_id, c.cat_name, count(cd.*)
from category c
   left join category_details cd 
       on c.cat_id = cd.cat_id
group by c.cat_id, c.cat_name
```

This will return each category with the count of category_details associated with it.  Using `LEFT JOIN` will return all categories -- replace with an `INNER JOIN` if you want only those with details.